# How to set empty value XamDateTimeEditor?

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I am learning  WPF and infragistics.I want to initialize a null value(set nothing like "") in XamDateTimeEditor, but whatever I try it has set to 01.01.0001.

After initialization if editor has clicked I want to set datetime.Today.

Any suggestions?

My best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it to a property which is of type Nullable DataTime type so the XamDataGrid's editor would fill the editor with the default value (null).

Code -

```
 private DateTime? _fromDT;

    public DateTime? FromDT
    {
        get { return _fromDT; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != this._fromDT)
            {
                this._fromDT = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FromDT");
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML -

```
my:XamDateTimeEditor Mask="{}{date} {time}" Value="{Binding Path=BindingDataContext.FromDT, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
```